# Adding dynamic columns to an excel report from mysql procedure

Tags: mysql

I am creating a procedure to download a report that contains 27 columns, and among them the client want three columns to come dynamically i.e it should be based on values from UI but I have hardcored the columns. So, how can I make the columns come dynamically based on values from UI.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [OUTFILE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select-into.html#:%7E:text=INTO%20OUTFILE%20is%20the%20complement,is%20no%20character%20set%20conversion.) to convert your `table` into `excel`, you can use multiple tables or add hard-coded data.

```
SELECT
    `table`.*,
    "Anything" as 'hardcored_Data'
INTO OUTFILE "PATH/export_excel.xls" FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
FROM
    `db`.`table`;
```

Run the below command to find the `PATH`

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "secure_file_priv";
```